# Default value of kwarg 'compression' in create_dataset() of h5py

Tags: python, compression, hdf5, h5py

what is the default value of the compression keyword argument of the function create_dataset in h5py, i.e. what value do I have to pass to get no compression?

I'm asking because I would like to have a flag which turns the compression on/off and I'd like to avoid to have a case switch every time I call the function, once with and once without the respective keyword.

Comment: [`None`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/_hl/dataset.py#L50).

Comment: Stupid me, of course i's None. I tried that, got an error and blamed it on this although it was a different problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610028/default-value-of-kwarg-compression-in-create-dataset-of-h5py#comment62703712_37610028) pointed out, the default compression keyword for no compression is `None`.